# Crear un ListView personalizado a partir de uno básico

Tags: android-studio, listview

Tengo una aplicación que lee el contenido de un `XML` remoto, lo guarda en el `ArrayList UnCurso` y me muestra por medio de un `ListView` básico los titulares de cada entrada del `XML`.

Quiero personalizar el `ListView` para que, además de mostrar los titulares, me muestre también la imagen que va asociada a cada titular. Para ello he creado también un `Layout` con el modelo de cada entrada o ítem del `ListView` llamado `ítem_List`.

Hasta aquí todo correcto, pero me he quedado atascado, no sé cómo debo modificar el `ArrayAdapter` para que me cree cada entrada del `ListView` con su `Titular` y su `Imagen`. Os dejo el código para que le echéis un vistazo y me orientéis sobre cómo debo modificar el `ArrayAdapter` para que me muestre en el `ListView` la información que quiero.

Este es el **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private URL url;
    private ArrayList<ElCurso> UnCurso;
    private String[] titulares;
    private ListView listadoTitulos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy permiso = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(permiso);

        listadoTitulos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.vtTitulares);
        UnCurso = new ArrayList<ElCurso>();

        try {
            url = new URL(" http://www.videotutoriales.es/android-xml/cursos.xml");
            leerxml();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Este es el adptador que quiero modificar para que me muestre el titular y una imagen
        ArrayAdapter adaptador  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,titulares);
        listadoTitulos.setAdapter(adaptador);


        listadoTitulos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this,Detalle_curso.class);
                intent.putExtra("CURSO", UnCurso.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void leerxml() {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory;
        XmlPullParser xml;

        int evento;

        boolean titulo;
        boolean precio;
        boolean imagen;
        boolean detalle;

        ArrayList<String> titulos;
        ArrayList<String> precios;
        ArrayList<String> imagenes;
        ArrayList<String> detalles;

        titulo = false;
        precio = false;
        imagen = false;
        detalle = false;

        titulos = new ArrayList<String>();
        precios = new ArrayList<String>();
        imagenes = new ArrayList<String>();
        detalles = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            xml=factory.newPullParser();
            xml.setInput(url.openStream(), "UTF-8");

            evento=xml.getEventType();

            while (evento != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){

                switch (evento){
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        if (xml.getName().equals("titulo")){
                            titulo = true;
                        }
                        if (xml.getName().equals("precio")){
                            precio = true;
                        }
                        if (xml.getName().equals("imagen")){
                            imagen = true;
                        }
                        if (xml.getName().equals("detalle")){
                            detalle = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        if (titulo){
                            titulos.add(xml.getText());
                        }
                        if (precio){
                            precios.add(xml.getText());
                        }
                        if (imagen){
                            imagenes.add(xml.getText());
                        }
                        if (detalle){
                            detalles.add(xml.getText());
                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if (xml.getName().equals("titulo")){
                            titulo = false;
                        }
                        if (xml.getName().equals("precio")){
                            precio = false;
                        }
                        if (xml.getName().equals("imagen")){
                            imagen = false;
                        }
                        if (xml.getName().equals("detalle")){
                            detalle = false;
                        }
                        break;

                }
                evento= xml.next();
            }

            titulares = new String[titulos.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < titulos.size(); i++){
                UnCurso.add(new ElCurso(titulos.get(i), detalles.get(i), imagenes.get(i), precios.get(i)));
                titulares[i] = titulos.get(i);
            }

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Este es el XML **ítem_List** con la interfaz de cada objeto del `ListView`

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Imagen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/LblTitulo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Titulo"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Y aquí está el objeto donde guardola información leída del xml

```
public class ElCurso implements Serializable{
    private String titulo;
    private String detalle;
    private String imagen;
    private String precio;

    public ElCurso(String titulo, String detalle, String imagen, String precio) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.detalle = detalle;
        this.imagen = imagen;
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public String getDetalle() {
        return detalle;
    }

    public String getImagen() {
        return imagen;
    }

    public String getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }
}
```

Aqui está el Detalle_curso donde cargo el detalle de cada curso en un nuevo layout.

```
public class Detalle_curso extends Activity{
private TextView txtTitulo;
private TextView txtDetalle;
private TextView txtPrecio;

private ImageView vistaImagen;
private Bitmap imagenCargada;
private String direccionImagen = "http://www.videotutoriales.es/android-xml/";


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detalle);

    txtTitulo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
    txtDetalle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDetalle);
    txtPrecio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPrecio);
    vistaImagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImagen);

    try {
        obtenerCurso();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void obtenerCurso() throws IOException {
    Intent intent  = getIntent();
    ElCurso uncurso = (ElCurso) intent.getSerializableExtra("CURSO");
    txtTitulo.setText(uncurso.getTitulo());
    txtDetalle.setText(uncurso.getDetalle());
    txtPrecio.setText(uncurso.getPrecio() + "Euros");
    direccionImagen = direccionImagen + uncurso.getImagen();

    descargarImagen(direccionImagen);
}

private void descargarImagen(String direccionImagen2) throws IOException {
    URL imagenURL = null;
    try {
        imagenURL = new URL(direccionImagen2);
        HttpURLConnection conn  = (HttpURLConnection) imagenURL.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        imagenCargada = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
        vistaImagen.setImageBitmap(imagenCargada);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Para eso debes implementar un clase que extienda de `Base Adapter`

ej:

```
 public class AdapterCursos extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<ElCurso> lista;


    public AdapterContactos(Context context, List<ElCurso> lista) {
        this.context = context;
        this.lista = lista;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fila_contacto, viewGroup, false);    
        ImagenView imagen = v.findViewById(R.id.Imagen)
        TextView tv = v.findViewById(R.id.LblTitulo);
        tv.setText(lista.get(position).getTitulo())



        return v;
    }
}
```

Y en tu Actividad llamarlo:

```
ArrayAdapter adaptador  = new AdapterCursos(this,cursos);//curos es una lista de tus objetos
listadoTitulos.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

Comment: Hola, estoy probando tu ejemplo, que es daoSession ?

Comment: lo he editado, esa linea no deberia ir

Comment: Hola Igmer, probando con tu adaptador de ejemplo "AdapterCursos" lo he arreglado para mi ejemplo pero me he quedado atascado a la hora de asignar la imagen al Imagview del adaptador, mira como me ha quedado el getView del adaptador

Comment: public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, viewGroup, false);
        ImageView imagen = v.findViewById(R.id.Imagen);
        TextView tv = v.findViewById(R.id.LblTitulo);
        tv.setText(lista.get(position).getTitulo());
        // imagen.setImageResource ( position ) no se como asignar la imagen al imageView;

        return v;
    }

Comment: donde tienes tu imagenes?

Comment: Están en el objeto UnCurso, los datos los obtengo de forma remota con la función leerxml().

Comment: es una url para la imagen?

Comment: No, la imagen la obtengo por medio de la funcion leerxml() del xml remoto y guardo toda la información de cada curso en el objeto UnCurso, después añado la url de la carpeta remota donde están almacenadas la imágenes al nombre de cada imagen para obtener la url completa de la imagen para visualizarla al hacer clic en un curso del ListView con otro layout, la clase que hace eso se llama Detalle_curso, acabo de editar la pregunta para incluirla.

Comment: por eso la imagen esta en un servidor remoto? se puede obtener por una url?

Comment: Si claro, la imagen se obtiene por medio de esta url: private String direccionImagen = "http://www.videotutoriales.es/android-xml/"; a la que despues se añade el nombre de cada imagen, este proceso se hace en la clase Detalle_curso.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que tu estas llamadole adaptador a lo que es tu objeto Curso ese objeto va a apasar al adapter

```
public class ElCursoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ElCurso> {    
    // Este es un adaptador custom

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
    }

    public ElCursoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ElCurso> elCurso) {
       //Constructor del adaptador donde Pones tu arraylist
       super(context, R.layout.item_user, users);    
    }

    @Override    
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {    
       // Obtener data por la posición    
       User user = getItem(position);        
       // Verificar si la vista se va a reutilizar sino se infla la vista      
       ViewHolder viewHolder;     
       if (convertView == null) {    
          // Se infla la vista    
          viewHolder = new ViewHolder();    
          LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());    
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_ElCurso, parent, false);    
          viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);//Algun tv    
          //Algun otro parametro lo pasas de la misma forma por ejemplo tu ImageView                      
          convertView.setTag(viewHolder);    
       } else {    
           //Cuando la vista se reutilzia    
           viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();    
       }

        //Asignamos los datos de la lista En el viewHolder

       viewHolder.name.setText(user.name);
       // Se regresa la vista     
       return convertView;
   }

}
```

Ahora Solo debes de asignar el Adaptador a tu ListView

```
//Se Crea El adaptador
ArrayList<ElCurso> arregloCursos = new ArrayList<ElCurso>();
ElCusoAdapter adapter = new       ElCursoAdapter(this, arregloCursos );   
//Se lo asignamos al ListView
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCurso);    
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[Fuente](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, he estado probando con tu ejemplo del adaptador "ElCursoAdapter" pero me muestra el ListView vacio, inspeccionando con el debuger veo que llega a cargar en el adaptador "adapter" los cursos dentro de mContext pero no me los muestra en el ListView, no se que es lo que estará mal, a ver si puedes revisar el código para averiguar el error.
Saludos y gracias.

Comment: //Se Crea El adaptador ------  esto es igual 
        ArrayList<ElCurso> arregloCursos = new ArrayList<ElCurso>();
        ElCursoAdapter adapter = new ElCursoAdapter ( this,arregloCursos );
        
 //Se lo asignamos al ListView   -----  aqui lo asigno a mi listview 
        ListView listadoTitulos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.vtTitulares);
        listadoTitulos.setAdapter(adapter);